# User not authenticated

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Im trying to download a file as described in [forge documentation.](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/#step-5-find-the-versions-of-an-item)

So im getting an access token with `scope=data:read` for the first 2 steps :

```
curl 
-v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' 
-X 'POST' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
-d 'client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=data:read'
```

It works up to the  `GET hubs/:hub_id/projects` endpoint.

Then, the `GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents` endpoint requires `data:write`, so im adding it:

```
curl 
-v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' 
-X 'POST' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
-d 'client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=data:read%20data:write'
```

It returns an access token without any issue, but when i use for this endpoint, i get a "User not authenticated" error.

I honestly dont know where its coming from, i tried without the url-encoded space as well, no difference.

Thanks in advance for any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Your request looks good. I tried it with my credentials and it was working, I was able to do "get contents" request, so you should take a look to your "get contents" request and be sure you well added your token into the request headers.

Comment: You don't need a data:write scope for [GetContents](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/)
required scope is only `data:read`.
I tested jus now, it works with `data:read` scope . 

`curl --request GET --url https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/{{projectId}/folders/{{folderId}}/contents --header 'Authorization: Bearer blah'`

Comment: thanks, indeed i did not need read scope.